# Why aren't my images loading now I've updated DomPDF to 2.0.3?

Tags: php, html, dompdf, html-pdf

I just updated from a fairly old version of DOMPDF and now can't see the images which were previously generating.

**This is how I'm calling the PDF generation. It generates everything on the PDF apart from the images.**

```
require_once 'dompdf_2-0-3/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
$options = new Options();
$options->set('isJavascriptEnabled', TRUE); 
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

$dompdf->loadHtml($html); // adds the html to the pdf
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait'); // paper size and orientation
$dompdf->render(); // Render the HTML as PDF
$date = (string)date("d.m.y");
$dompdf->stream("Yandiya Calc Results ".($date));
```

**Below is an example of where I use images in the HTML document.**

```
<div class="Page3 page-break">
    <div class="House_Back_Container"><img src="images/PDF/buildingInformation.png" class="Template"></img></div>
    <div class="House_Type_Icon"><img src="images/{HOUSE_TYPE_ICON}" class="House_Type_Icon"></img></div>
    <h1 class="House_Type">{HOUSE_TYPE}</h1>
    <h1 class="House_Age">{HOUSE_AGE}</h1>
    <h1 class="Tariff_Value">{TARIFF}</h1>
    <img src="images/{LOCATION_ICON}" class="Location"></img>
</div>
```

Obviously, before I updated, the images were rendering with the PDF generation, so it's been confusing me as to what has changed since.

Text displayed as {EXAMPLE} is for my PHP file where the dompdf is ran to replace with variables that I send through AJAX from my client-side.

Comment: I had the exact same problem since I updated to later version. After many attempts I solved by changing the relative URL to complete URL. Example: `img/a.png` to `http://localhost/img/a.png`